# How to use docker cli in golang to create subnet

Tags: docker, go

I'm trying to create a docker network for my application written in Golang.

I'm aware that I can use [this `NetworkCreate` function](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker/client#Client.NetworkCreate), but I'm not sure how to specify the network option.

In the regular terminal console, I can just create the network with

```
docker network create -d bridge --subnet=174.3.12.5/16 mynet
```

But how to use the `NetworkCreate()` as an equivalent for this network creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types/network"
    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
)

func main() {
    cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.FromEnv)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    newnetwork := types.NetworkCreate{IPAM: &network.IPAM{
        Driver: "default",
        Config: []network.IPAMConfig{network.IPAMConfig{
            Subnet: "174.3.12.5/16",
        }},
    }}

    res, err := cli.NetworkCreate(context.Background(), "test", newnetwork)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(res)

}
```

this is a minimal implementable example. the name for driver is `default`.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the network options via the `NetworkCreate` options struct.

If you want to convert the command `docker network create -d bridge --subnet=174.3.12.5/16 mynet` to a golang equivalent, It'll look something like this:

```golang
networkResponse, err := client.NetworkCreate(context.Background(), "mynet", types.NetworkCreate{
    Driver: "bridge",
    IPAM: &network.IPAM{
        Config: network.IPAMConfig{
            Subnet: "174.3.12.5/16",
        },
    },
})
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `exec.Command(...).CombinedOutput()`